# Hibernate Search Indexer process hangs after half work

Tags: hibernate-search

I have 7 entity classes to index using Hibernate Search. Having tried both MassIndexer and FlushToIndexes, the indexer process churned away through the smallest entites but the largest entities/tables did not finish, even though a MassIndexerProgressMonitor told the indexing finished. The process just hangs when it hits 100-200 MB allocated. I want to ensure indexing process ends properly.

**Questions: Is the code correct? Should hibernate or database settings be tuned?**

---

Environment: 64-bit Windows 7, JBoss, Struts2, Hibernate, Hibernate Search, Lucene, SQL Server. The Hibernate Search Index is placed in filesystem.

---

MassIndexer code sample:

```
  final Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
  final FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
  MassIndexerProgressMonitor monitor = new IndexProgressMonitor("Kanalregister");
  fullTextSession.createIndexer()
                 .purgeAllOnStart(true)
                 .progressMonitor(monitor)
                 .batchSizeToLoadObjects(BATCH_SIZE)    // 250000
                 .startAndWait();
```

---

FlushToIndexes code sample: (from Hibernate ref. doc.) (seems to index ok, but never ends)

```
  final Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
  final FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
  fullTextSession.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
  fullTextSession.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
  Transaction t1 = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
  // Scrollable results will avoid loading too many objects in memory
  ScrollableResults results = fullTextSession.createCriteria(Land.class)
                                             .setFetchSize(BATCH_SIZE) // 250000
                                             .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
  int index = 0;
  while (results.next()) {
     index++;
     fullTextSession.index(results.get(0)); // index each element
     if (index % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
        fullTextSession.flushToIndexes(); // apply changes to indexes
        fullTextSession.clear(); // free memory since the queue is processed
     }
  }
  t1.commit();
```

---

The code is verified to end when mocking all indexing work, using the following setting in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.worker.backend">blackhole</property>
```

Comment: Hi, could you clarify: - which database - which versions - which of the two methods is working?

Comment: Hi, I'm using SQL Server 2008. MassIndexer works half-way, FlushToIndexes is able to build index for small tables. (Ops, while trying a larger table, I got some configuration errors for the larger table, hang on, I'll fix)

Comment: Your batch_size is insanely high: usually it should be something between 5 and 100; still I don't think this explains the problem. Could you check GC activity and post a full thread dump? This might be more suited to the Hibernate Search forums https://forum.hibernate.org/viewforum.php?f=9

Comment: Good idea, I will check those forums, and update here when I find answers.

Comment: On batch size; I even tried with a batch size of 25 million, all to rule out that there could be a capacity limit.For now, this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is validated and correct.

My problem with the console not ending is thought to be related to Eclipse, as a printout at end of main() was indeed displayed.

There were some missing entity classes (in my model) which were not reported properly. Once I got notified of those and added them to my model, the indexing process ended successfully for MassIndexer, as evidenced by 3+ files in each directory in the lucene index.